# SharedPreferences в классе BroadcastReceiver не обновляет значение

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, android-shared-preferences

Класс RepeatingAlarmService работает в цикле (раз в минуту):

```
    public class RepeatingAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver  { 

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = referenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

            String ready = prefs.getString("interval", "");

            System.out.println("READY: "+ready);

}

}
```

Меняю в настройках значение поля `interval` - в файле `/data/data/app/shared_prefs/app_preferences.xml` всё меняется, через другие классы то же всё отлично считывается (включая сервисы), а вот через `BroadcastReceiver` как будто данное значение кешируется! Настройка меняется, а `BroadcastReceiver` показывает старое значение. Вот нашёл похожий вопрос, но там парню не ответили: [Тыц!](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1072207/android-nastroyki-keshiruutsya-i-tolko-po-proshestvii-vremeni-obnovlyautsya)

В чём может быть затык?

Comment: Покажите код как вы меняете значение преференсов

Comment: @Barmaley Меняю через PreferenceManager, вопрос не в этом, а в том что именно в классе RepeatingAlarmService при считывании значения оно не меняется на новое, а кешируется и выводит предыдущее. Из других классов всё читается как положено.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну тогда все понятно. Дело в том, что по умолчанию `SharedPreference` не поддерживает актуализацию данных в между процессами. Иными словами если изменение данных производится в одном процессе не гарантируется, что в другом процессе изменения будут отражены.

Чтобы побороть это вам надо создавать преференсы с флагом `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` - [читаем здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! Работает: Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS