# Не обновляется значение из sharedPreferences. Android

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

1) Есть основная активность, где время от времени сохраняются значения:

```
        AddToLog("-сохраняем настройки");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("cooki", SaveSett);
        edit.commit();
        edit.apply();
        AddToLog("-и тут-же читаем настройки,записалось ли?");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        uid = sharedPreferences2.getString("cooki", "");
        AddToLog("uid2:" + uid);
```

2) Есть сервис, который раз в несколько минут эти настройки читает:

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences mSettings;
        AddToLog("--запустилось периодическое событие...");

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        uid = sharedPreferences.getString("cooki", "");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "load uid2:" + uid);
        sharedPreferences=null;
        System.gc();

        hello=context;
        new ParseTask().execute();
    }
```

Суть проблемы:

Вызываем (1)-> Сервис читает "cooki" !!! И результат - не меняется пока приложение не снято. В то-же во время чтения cooki в самой активности - читается верное значение.

Comment: `commit` и `aplly` делают одно и то же (записывают значения в файл с настройками) , с той лишь разницей, что первый в основном потоке, второй - асинхронно. Их не надо вызывать оба, а только одно, предпочтительно `apply`

Comment: Та это я уже от безысходности... Не помогает даже перестарт сервиса и "чистка" классов.            sharedPreferences=null;
            sharedPreferences2=null;
            System.gc();
            stopService(new Intent(Form1.this, MyService.class));
            startService(new Intent(Form1.this, MyService.class));

Comment: Такое ощущение что файл с настройками "блокируется" основной активностью, и не дает читать изменения, пока активность работает.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427646/177345

Comment: Ага, уже копаю в эту сторону.. Не могу только сообразить как MODE_MULTI_PROCESS добавить в SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 1):

Что бы все наверняка работало, храните статическую ссылку на SharedPreferences в классе, который наследуется от Application(OnCreate методе можно инициализировать их). Установите этот класс в манифесте. Потом добавте метод get для получения этих SharedPreferences. А потом просто везде ее используйте, тогда у вас точно будет достут к одним и темже SharedPreferences.

Вот пример класса. Не забудьте только добавить его в манифест.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
private static SharedPreferences m_sharedPreferences;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    m_sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}

public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(){
    return m_sharedPreferences;
}
```

}

Comment: Не совсем представляю как это сделать.. Я же из сервиса читаю настройки. Это для андроида как я понимаю считается отдельным приложением.

Comment: Нет, вы не правы. В андроиде все делится на таски, а не на приложения. Так вот сервисы и активити за частую находятся в одном таске, скажу даже более, основная часть сервисов выполняется в главном потоке. Отсюда, инстанс класса Application создается при запуске активити, сервисов и броадкаст ресиверов. У вас будет равноправный доступ к классу, который вы унаследуете от Application, из любого места в приложении. Вывод, все будет работать. Я так делаю переодически.

Comment: Не будет работь только если вы используете сервис, который работает в отдельном потоке, например, такой как IntentService.

Comment: Видимо это никак не решает проблемы в вопросе потому, что в одном потоке и так отовсюду можно получить доступ к преференсам через `PreferenceManager`, а в разных потоках это не будет работать.

Comment: Как знать, андроид и не такие капризы выдает, так что может и решить)